# Having trouble making an AJX call in Ionic 4

Tags: android, ajax, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I am making an app that will fetch the MySQL data using AJAX request and will post some data in the Database. It's an issue that it is not making an AJAX call in my project

I am working on Ionic 4 and PHP-MySQL as Backend service

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { data } from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  public press() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
    $.ajax({
      url: "demo_test.txt", // or any URL
      success: function(result) {
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  }
}
```

I want to make an AJAX call from remote HTML, PHP or text file in my Ionic 4 App.

Answer (score 1):

You should use httpclient from angular/http. that is very straight thing.

> https://angular.io/guide/http

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data)
}, err => {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how my code should be written in the way you mentioned?